# Cant get correct output in program

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    fstream file("file.txt");
    file << "this is new line" << endl;
    file.flush();
    string c;
    file >> c;
    cout << c << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

when i run this output is empty, if i remove line `file << "this is new line" << endl;` I'm getting correct output, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing to the file, you are moving the internal file pointer to the end of it.  This means the the next time you read, you will be at the end of the file, and so nothing will be read.

Look at `seek()` for moving the file pointer.